# php load data local infile path error

Tags: php

So, I wanna to get file path and then insert that into mysql.

This is the code:

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

include "config.php";

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'" .
                      " INTO TABLE ponuda FIELDS TERMINATED BY '    '");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

This is the path I receive:

```
string 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\php11EF.tmp'
```

But, I got mysql error saying this:

```
Could not load. Can't find file 'C:UsersxxxAppDataLocalTempphp1FA6.tmp'.
```

Why are slashes removed? What I doing wrong. Tried to search for a problem but didn't find any results.

p.s. I want to upload that file from my local PC.

EDIT: if I change "\" to this "/" in path it works well, but how can I use original file path, not temp one because that file doesn't exist in temp?

Comment: Change the \'s to /'s it seems (don't use Windows myself, [but I see the comments here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html)

Comment: That seems to work. But the problem is path. How can I use original path, not the temp one?

Comment: The original path? That would be on the users computer... so no, no dice? Or do I misunderstand you? You can move the file to wherever you like of course.

Answer (score 2):

OK, managed to find error.

Now it's working:

```
<?php

$file = str_replace("\\", "/", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

include "config.php";

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'" .
                      " INTO TABLE ponuda FIELDS TERMINATED BY '    '");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}

?>
```